# How to get cosine similiarity for 2 different lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, vector, cosine-similarity

I'm trying to get cosine similarity for 2 sets of data (with unequal lengths).

1. Test set contains 4 random similar images from google.
2. Training set contains 1 similar image to test set from google.

Following the code im using to do the same by converting image to vectors and calculating cosine similarity

```py
import os

from PIL import Image
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

from img_to_vec import Img2Vec
import numpy as np

test_path = '/Users/Desktop/img_vec/test'
train_path = '/Users/Desktop/img_vec/train'

print("Getting vectors for test images...\n")
img2vec = Img2Vec()

# For each test image, we store the filename and vector as key, value in a dictionary
pics = {}
for file in os.listdir(test_path):
    filename = os.fsdecode(file)
    img = Image.open(os.path.join(test_path, filename))
    vec = img2vec.get_vec(img)
    pics[filename] = vec
# print (pics)
pic_name = {}
for file1 in os.listdir(train_path):
    filename1 = os.fsdecode(file1)
    img1 = Image.open(os.path.join(train_path, filename1))
    vec1 = img2vec.get_vec(img1)
    pic_name[filename1] = vec1
# print(pic_name)

vec1 = np.array([pics])
vec2 = np.array([pic_name])

sims = {}
for key in list(pics.keys()):
    print(key)
    sims[key] = cosine_similarity(vec1[vec2].reshape((1, -1)), vec1[key].reshape((1,   -1)))[0][0]

d_view = [(v, k) for k, v in sims.items()]
d_view.sort(reverse=True)
for v, k in d_view:
    print(v, k)
```

However, I'm unable to resolve the following error:

> sims[key] = cosine_similarity(vec1[vec2].reshape((1, -1)), vec1[key].reshape((1, -1)))[0][0]
> IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type

I tried to compute cosine similarity in Python manually (using numpy) by using a specialised library. It doesn't work. I believe it's an issue with dtype.

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
 
# vectors
a = np.array([1,2,3])
b = np.array([1,1,4])
 
# manually compute cosine similarity
dot = np.dot(a, b)
norma = np.linalg.norm(a)
normb = np.linalg.norm(b)
cos = dot / (norma * normb)
 
# use library, operates on sets of vectors
aa = a.reshape(1,3)
ba = b.reshape(1,3)
cos_lib = cosine_similarity(aa, ba)
```

Any help / guidance / alternative is much appreciated.

Comment: the above code works if all the values are present in a single data set (test + train). However i have 2 different set with different lengths and want to find cosin similarity between them.

Comment: cosin similarity didnt work between 2 different data sets, hence i still used the same line of code `sims[key] = cosine_similarity(pics[pic_name].reshape((1, -1)), pics[key].reshape((1, -1)))[0][0]` and fixed the `pic_name` value

Answer (score 0):

`vec1 = np.array([pics])` 
`vec2 = np.array([pic_name])`

I don't see the need to do this.

Also, in the line where error is coming, the error is present at:

`vec1[vec2].reshape((1, -1))`

because you're indexing `vec1` using `vec2`. I suppose you mean to put `key` instead of `vec2`.

Comment: replacing with `key` instead of `vec2` resulted in the following error `IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices` and removing vec1, vec 2 resulted in error  -     `sims[key] = cosine_similarity(pics[pic_name].reshape((1, -1)), pics[key].reshape((1, -1)))[0][0]
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'`